# Noclassdeffounderror DataBufferByte exception Freaking Math open source ios

Tags: ios, math, libgdx, robovm, freak

I've got an open source game base on Libgdx 
**at https://github.com/miniclassic/freakingmath** 
that called Freaking Math Open Source. 
It's addictive,funny game and support mutilple plat form. It's ok on Android. But when i compile and run on device for ios by Robovm, i got "Noclassdeffounderror DataBufferByte exception" with facebook share function. It take screenshot then share on facebook wall.
This is functon:

```
public static void saveScreenshot(File file, byte[] pixels, int width, int height, boolean hasAlpha) throws IOException {
    DataBufferByte dataBuffer = new DataBufferByte(pixels, pixels.length);

    PixelInterleavedSampleModel sampleModel = new PixelInterleavedSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, 4, 4 * width, getOffsets(hasAlpha));

    WritableRaster raster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, dataBuffer, new Point(0, 0));

    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(getColorModel(hasAlpha), raster, false, null);

    ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
}
```

Who can help me resolve it??
Thank u so much!

Comment: Can you include the complete backtrace from the exception?

Comment: Are you sure that works on Android? It shouldn't.

Comment: I sure about it work on Android ! @P.T: ok, i will post log soon, thank you!!

Comment: Thank you, i try some other method for take screenshot in libgdx but image return is blank image. I also try call to ios screenshot method  via binding robovm, but it still return blank image. So mad! Need your helppppp!